# How to add dynamical form values from different names to same field in sql using php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Creating a resume builder website in which there could be multiple or no values for fields like skills, education..etc. I have made a '+' sign which increments the name of the div tag by 1 (using javascript). so on pressing the '+' sign, the name becomes 'skills1'. There could be variable quantity for these. How to add all these skills (skill1,skill2,skill3......) into the same field in sql table (skill)

```
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">School/College/University</label>&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="institute1" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">School/College/University</label>&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="institute2" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">School/College/University</label>&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="institute3" class="form-control">
</div>
```

The problem is that we dont know how many institutes are going to be added. What PHP code should be used here?

Tried to concatenate but to concatenate, the value should be there in the sql server.

Comment: Concatenation is not the solution. You have to create a separate table to hold these values. Each value will be a separate row in that new table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing multiple data with the same name, you can use array. Instead of doing this:

```
name="institute1", name="institute2"
```

you can do like this:

```
name="institute[]", name="institute[]"
```

then in your PHP, it will give you an array value.

```
var_dump($_POST['institute[]']);
```